# Help with the theorem: B(V,W) is complete if W is

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

I having some trouble with the proof of $\mathbf{B}(V,W)$ being a Banach space if $W$ is, where $\mathbf{B}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the space of bounded linear operators $V\to W$.

I know there are other posts about this theorem but I would like know If my understanding is correct.

**My Questions**

(1) First is $||T_n||$ the operator norm of linear operator $T_n$?

meaning: $||T_n|| = \sup\{T_n(x) : x \in V$ and $||x||\leq 1\}$

$||T_m(x) -T(x)|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

This holds as $T(x)$ was defined as the limit of $T_n(x)$ meaning: $T(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}T_n(x)$ and that $\{T_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence that converges to $T(x)$

(2) Is my proof of the following correct?:

I believe that $\textbf{B}(V,W)$ is a vector space.

as both $T_n$ , $T$ $\in \textbf{B}(V,W)$ thus $(T_n-T) \in \textbf{B}(V,W)$

as shown that $||(T_m -T)(x)||=||T_m(x) -T(x)|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $x\in V$ including if $||x||= 1$, then by theorem 03.11,

$||(T_m -T)|| = \sup \{||(T_m -T)(x)||: ||x|| = 1\} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

which implies: $||T_m -T||\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$

Then in summary:

It is shown that $T \in \textbf{B}(V,W)$, and that $||T_m -T||  < \epsilon$ proves that any Cauchy sequence $\{T_n\}$ converges to $T$, thus making $\textbf{B}(V,W)$ a Banach space.

Comment: What is your question? "Question" (2) explains the red underlined part, but does not mention any doubts

Comment: And yes, $\|T_n\|$ will be the linear operator norm

Comment: @FShrike , Thank your for your reply .For the red underlined part I am not sure how they got from $||T_m(x) -T(x)|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to $||T_m -T||\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I then tried to prove it but not sure if my reasoning throughout my "proof" is valid and wanted to know if it was ok

Comment: Ok. By the way, the two images you posted aren't especially relevant, and make your post harder to parse. Please avoid images where possible

Comment: I've made some edits I feel are appropriate for readability

Comment: @FShrike , ok great. I was not sure if I proved all the information that was needed so I added everything that I thought was related.

And to be 100% sure for question (2), is this acceptable?

Comment: What you wrote looks fine. It is a common (purely aesthetic!) theme to bound by $\varepsilon/2$, take a supremum to get potential equality, and claim $\lt\varepsilon$. Do bear in mind that $\|T_m-T\|\le\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon$ would also be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been struggling with this theorem for a while